# Laravel npm run dev ошибка выдает

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, npm, node-modules

При запуске npm run dev выдает ошибку

@ development: `cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js`

Я пробовал npm install cross-env --save-dev не помогло, пробовал установить webpack-cli тоже не помогло. В чем причина?

2) Второй вопрос почему когда пиши npm install не устанавливается node_modules. А когда пишу npm install --dev or npm install --only=dev сработает. Но эту команду после установки ларавел первым нужно написать ато node_modules не будет устанавливаться.

Все делаю как в документаций, но выдает ошибку. Я хочу устанавливать vue на laravel, из за этого куча ошибок выходить. Когда фронт часть чисто на js была все отлична работало, как установил vue куча ошибок выдал

Answer (score 1):

```
rm -rf node_modules
rm package-lock.json yarn.lock
npm cache clear --force
npm install
```

как удалите все и почистите кэш, можно еще добавить:

```
npm install --global cross-env
```

Comment: rm: cannot remove 'yarn.lock': Нет такого файла или каталога

Comment: все нормально,package-lock.json удалило, тогда дальше

Comment: это если вы используете yarn

Comment: Error: Cannot find module 'webpack-cli'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:636:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:562:25)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:692:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:25:18)
    at runCommand.then (/usr/local/ampps/www/larvue2/blog/node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js:143:5)

Comment: npm rm -g webpack-cli и в проекте npm i -D webpack-cli

Comment: сейчас решим твою проблему)

Comment: One CLI for webpack must be installed. These are recommended choices, delivered as separate packages:
 - webpack-cli (https://github.com/webpack/webpack-cli)
   The original webpack full-featured CLI.
We will use "npm" to install the CLI via "npm install -D".
Do you want to install 'webpack-cli' (yes/no): yes
Installing 'webpack-cli' (running 'npm install -D webpack-cli')...

Comment: npm WARN The package webpack is included as both a dev and production dependency.
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.11 (node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.11: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})

Comment: вы запускаете в Винде?

Comment: 1) Устанавил ларавел
   composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel blog
2) Устанавил vue на проект
   composer require laravel/ui
   php artisan ui vue
3) Устанавил node_modules
   npm install --dev or npm install --only=dev
4) npm run dev выдает ошибку cross-env

Comment: linux debain.:)

Comment: и сейчас выдает, попробуйте запустить

Comment: Но у меня 2 ОС в одном ноут винда и линукс. Диск на два разделил

Comment: если проект на лине стоит, то должен зауститься.

Comment: Да вот не знаю все сделал как в документаций, не получается

Comment: бывает такое, прежде чем запустить проект, нужно проверить, что бы все, что необходимо для проекта стояло на ПК.

Comment: Раньше когда vue не была npm run dev работало, а когда установил vue начались проблемы

Comment: но по идее, последние ворнинги не должны мешать запуску лары.

Comment: можете скинуть видео или документация/статья по установке vue на laravel.

Comment: вы эту команду запустили?? php artisan ui vue

Comment: я этой всегда пользовался https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/frontend

Comment: да в самом начале

Comment: потом истал и потом дев?

Comment: дев? php artisan ui vue --dev ?

Comment: что бы на глобальном уровне установить зависимости и работало и подтягивало все корректно.

Comment: без --dev рекомендуется документацией.. да и мне в принципе никогда не нужно было.

Comment: рекомендую, удалить все. Почистить кэш и логи в ноде, птом почистить в компосере и устанавливать.  Берите все инфо из https://laravel.com/, это офиц дока. Если возникают проблемы, в гите у лары есть форум и там оперативно решат вопрос, но проверьте заранее настройки.

Comment: хорошо спасибо большое

Comment: не за что и удачи, у меня в первый раз при установке так же все пошло по п.. потом с опытом нормально)